# php interpratation of ':' and '?'

Tags: php, operators

I'm working on a wordpress widget that utilizes Johnathan Christopher's 'Widget Image Field' pluggin. I'm confused by this line of code.

```
$image_id = esc_attr( isset( $instance[$this->image_field] ) ? $instance[$this->image_field] : 0 );
```

What does the '?' and ':' do?

Comment: It's the _ternary operator_. Stack Overflow is not supposed to be a substitute for reading documentation.

Comment: Is_this_a_question ? Yes_it_is : No_it_isn't;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same that:

```
if(isset( $instance[$this->image_field]))
{
    $image_id =  $instance[$this->image_field];
}
else
{
     $image_id = 0;
}
```

This is the ternary operator. 
[Here](http://phpmaster.com/using-the-ternary-operator/) you can learn about.

Comment: You should not ask such a question, and go to practice before asking such question on SO (which is not here for that)